# Golden retriever: will fur grow back after infection?

Tags: dogs, health, shedding

My Golden Retriever is 1.5 yrs old. He lost his fur in the back and tail recently, and vet suggested it might be bacterial infection. For a week we gave anti-bacterial medication and looks like the shedding slowed down.

Now his tail looks like a Labrador. Will it grow back to golden style?

Comment: All I can say is "probably". If the follicles (the cells that produce hair) are not destroyed, they will continnue producing hair. But there is not enough information to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often if a dog gets shaved for surgery or something like that, the hair won't grow back until the next "shedding cycle" (I'm sure there is a more scientific word for that). I think this is only for dogs like retrievers that have fur, compared to something such as  poodle that has to get hair cuts all the time. I would be patient and I am hopeful it will grow back for your pup!

Comment: Thanks Selene. Yes, now my Golden has fur back as normal. I also give him skin and fur supplement which could also be the reason.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Selva! I give my lab a fish oil supplement every day and it really seems to help keep her fur soft and healthy. I'm sure your supplement helped as well.